# How do I correctly ignore a parameter when vectorizing a function it with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

The function I am vectorizing is Loanp and I want it to ignore the parameter 'coeff' which is an array. Here is the code I wrote after looking online/at documentation:

```
vLoanp = np.vectorize(Loanp, excluded = ['coeff'])
```

It still vectorizes the parameter, so I get `IndexError: Invalid index to scalar variable`.

Comment: `np.vectorize` won't give you a real speedup compared to a normal for loop. It would be nice to see your function `Loanp` to analyse whether it could be already written in vectorized form

Comment: By correctly following the example in the `vectorize` docs!

Comment: where do you get the IndexError?

Comment: Note that the vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html